# Persistent login after user's signing up and confirms their accounts through email, and after they log in

Tags: php, reactjs, authentication

I'm creating an authentication system based on a token generated in PHP, that the user has to confirm their account through an email sent to them after signing up, and the token is validated after the user clicks on the link that is supposed to process the PHP page responsible for token and then to a Thank you for confirmation page, but instead, they're redirected to the login page, and that also happens with the other pages, even though I set up session_start in the backend.

EDIT: The other issue is with persistent login, for now I'm using useEffect and sessionStorage, JSON.stringify to get the user's session set in login.php, and make use of axios.get in the Dashboard (main page after login/signup) only, where in other files I make use of sessionStorage and JSON parse only, however because of that I'm getting undefined array key "user_id" for profile update, so I'm trying to make use of axios.get in every file, only to get redirected back to login, as if I didn't login from the start, I believe it is either errors I cannot see in backend, or I did something wrong when I was trying to get the backend data to frontend.

**Dashboard.js**

```
function Dashboard() {

const navigate = useNavigate();
const[user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
      const storedUser = 
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
      if(storedUser){
        setUser(storedUser);
      } else {
        axios.get("http://localhost/bachelor_exam/login.php")
        .then((response) => {
          if(response.data.length) {
            const user = {
              user_id: response.data[0].user_id,
              first_name: response.data[0].first_name,
              last_name: response.data[0].last_name,
              email: response.data[0].email,
              company: response.data[0].company,
              phone_number: response.data[0].phone_number,
              verified: response.data[0].verified,
              token: response.data[0].token,
            };
            setUser(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
          } else {
            navigate("/login");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          navigate("/login");
        });
      }
    }, [navigate]);
```

**Profile.js, as an example of how I've done in other files:**

```
const Profile = () => {

const navigate = useNavigate();
const[user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const storedUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
    if(storedUser){
        setUser(storedUser);
    } else {
        navigate("/login");
    }

}, [navigate]);
```

**update_profile.php, where I do have the problem with undefined array_key "user_id"**

```
try {
    
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $updatePassHash = password_hash($changedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $q->bindValue(":email", $changedEmail);
    $q->execute();
    $rowCheckEmail = $q->fetch();

    if($rowCheckEmail > 0){
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode("The email is already taken");
        exit();

    } else {

       $db->beginTransaction(); 

       //the user changes their first name
       $q = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name = :first_name WHERE user_id = :user_id");
       $q->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id);
       $q->bindValue(":first_name", $changedFirstName);
       $q->execute();
```

For the undefined array key, I have seen videos where you come up with if(isset), but that didn't work, and from the if(!isset), I could see the user ID is not being set properly, despite the sessions I have started in every page of PHP, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: What parts of your code have you tried changing to resolve the issue?

Comment: I've been trying to change most of the code in the frontend, the useEffect hook and the axios requests, so that I could reflect the backend in the frontend that the user has been verified and logged in. Moreover, in confirm_account.php, I also put the link of accoutConfirmed in header, together with ?token=$token, only to get a "Cannot GET /accountconfirmed" error.

Comment: An another thing worth to mention is that the problem might be the "Cannot GET /accountconfirmed", even though http://localhost:3000/accountconfirmed is the right path of the page, (the problem lies to this after updating the token and verified columns in database: header("Location: http://localhost:3000/accountconfirmed");
    echo json_encode("Success");
    exit(); ) which makes me think if there's another way of redirecting the user to AccountConfirmed.js after the confirm_account.php has validated and verified the user.

Comment: When you make a redirect using the Location header from your PHP code, you actually tell the browser to navigate to that URL. So the browser tries to call the backend under that address. You actually want to load the frontend React application and make it navigate to that URL. What you need to do, is to configure your server that serves the JS files for your react app to also serve those files under the `/accountconfirmed` path.

Comment: Another thing — when you paste code to a question try to paste only the relevant code. E.g., you could rather skip the parts that validate whether the password has enough numbers in it, etc.

Comment: Michal Trojanowski the path issue has been resolved and I will take that into account for next time, but I do also have a problem with the persistent login of the user, as for now, I used axios.get to get the data of logged in the session user, with session set in Dashboard only, in other pages using the useEffect and JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"), and it kinda works, but then I'm not able to update their profile for example, due to undefined array key user_id in backend, so I make use of axios.get in every file, and I get redirected back to login.

Comment: I've just edited the main post with the respective files that I was talking about in the previous comment, put relevant code, and removed the other files.